# the tzaddik decrees it and HaKadosh Baruch Hu fulfills it

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, talmud-gemara, tzaddikim, masechet-moed-katan

Someone mentioned that the *Gemara* in *Mo'ed Katan* (16b) says:
צדיק גוזר והקב"ה מקים, *the tzaddik decrees it and HaKadosh Baruch Hu fulfills it.*

I looked in *Mo'ed Katan* and could not find צדיק גוזר והקב"ה מקים.

Does anyone a *Gemara* that states these exact words?

Comment: Sounds like a strange mistake to make. Can you provide any more detail about the context in which this was mentioned?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I saw צדיק גוזר והקב"ה מקים written on page 392 in Rav Schwab on Prayer.

Comment: see something similar in Talmud [Shabbos 59b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=59b&format=pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those exact words do not appear. However, in *Taanis* 23a, there is a *braissa* that presents the idea:

> תנו רבנן מה שלחו בני לשכת הגזית לחוני המעגל (איוב כב, כח) ותגזר אומר ויקם לך ועל דרכיך נגה אור ותגזר אומר אתה גזרת מלמטה והקדוש ברוך הוא מקיים מאמרך מלמעלה
>
> The rabbis taught: What was the word which the Sanhedrin sitting in the chamber of marble sent to Honi Hama'gel after the occurrence? They cited the passage [Job, xxii. 28]: "And if thou decree a thing, it will be fulfilled unto thee; and upon thy ways the light will shine," and said: "Thou hast decreed below, and the Holy One, blessed be He, ratified it above, and the generation which was in darkness thou hast enlightened with thy prayer.

Answer (score 2):

The closest text we have is a [*Medrash*](https://www.sefaria.org/Bemidbar_Rabbah.14.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) but in the plural:

> כְּשֶׁהַצַּדִּיקִים גּוֹזְרִים הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מְקַיֵּם דִּבְרֵיהֶם, *when the tzaddikim decree, Hashem fulfills their words*.

However, the concept does exist in two *Mesechtos*:

[*Mo’ed Katan*](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.16b.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): צדיק שאני גוזר גזרה ומבטלה, *As I [G-d], issue a decree and the righteous person nullifies it.*

[*Kesubos*](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.103b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): ותגזר אומר ויקם לך, *You shall also decree a thing, and it shall be established unto you.*

Answer (score 1):

Similar concept in Chullin 60b

> רב אסי רמי כתיב {בראשית א-יב} ותוצא הארץ דשא בתלת בשבתא וכתיב {בראשית ב-ה} וכל שיח השדה טרם יהיה בארץ במעלי שבתא מלמד שיצאו דשאים ועמדו על פתח קרקע עד שבא אדם הראשון ובקש עליהם רחמים וירדו גשמים וצמחו **ללמדך שהקב''ה מתאוה לתפלתן של צדיקים** רב נחמן בר פפא הויא ליה ההיא גינתא שדי ביה ביזרני ולא צמח בעא רחמי אתא מיטרא וצמח אמר היינו דרב אסי

Rav Asi says that the grass didn’t grow until אדם הראשון came and prayed for it. To tell you Hashem is מתאוה to the prayers of Tzadikim.

And there is a second case brought that Rav Nachman Bar Pappa planted seeds, but they didn’t grow and he prayed for rain, and thus proves the same point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALgU89jYZcg) of Reb Ahron Leib Shteinman Zt"l talking about this. He explains what the proper context is for this Gemara.